# How to validate several rules with 'required_if' on Laravel 5.5?

Tags: validation, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

I am trying to validate the 'uuid' field so that it is mandatory if the 'typeUUID' field is marked 'type1'.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'uuid' => 'required_if:typeUUID,==,type1|alpha_dash|size:36',
]);
```

If I select the value 'type1' it indicates that the field is mandatory, and when I set another value that is not mandatory, it validates' alpha_dash 'and' size: 36 and does not accept the field since it is sent empty.

What is the right way?

I know I could do it with a condition by checking the type at the beginning and then applying one or more rules. But I would like to know the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, is to add the rule 'nullable' after the rule 'required_if'.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'uuid' => 'required_if:typeUUID,==,type1|nullable|alpha_dash|size:36',
]);
```